# A  list of symmetric statistics

Tags: co.combinatorics, reference-request, big-list

I would like to have a list of pairs (or tuples) of combinatorial statistics that are (known or conjectured) to have symmetric distribution.  Ideally, something like this has already been compiled, otherwise, maybe [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/101265/a-list-of-symmetric-statistics) is the place to do so.

Some examples:

- on Dyck paths: area and bounce, returns to the axis and length of the last descent
- on permutations: major index and number of inversions
- on perfect matchings, set partitions and permutations: crossings and nestings, the maximal crossing number and the maximal nesting number

Maybe it's best to have one family of objects per answer.  Edit: originally, I had only *joint* symmetric distribution in mind.  However, lists of equidistributed tuples are also very good to have.  Please indicate in your answer what your tuple satisfies!

Definitions:

Statistics $stat_1,stat_2,\dots,stat_n$ on a set $X$ are *equidistributed* if 
$$\sum_{x\in X}q^{stat_1(x)} = \sum_{x\in X}q^{stat_2(x)} = \dots \sum_{x\in X}q^{stat_n(x)}.$$

A tuple of statistics $(stat_1,stat_2,\dots,stat_n)$ on a set $X$ has a *symmetric* distribution if its generating function
$$F_{stat_1,stat_2}(q,t) := \sum_{x\in X}x_1^{stat_1(x)}x_2^{stat_2(x)}\dots x_n^{stat_n(x)}$$
is symmetric in $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$.

Answer (score 6):

We started writing up combinatorial statistics on http://www.findstat.org . There you already find some (but not yet many) symmetric statistics. People who are interested and would like to contribute are very welcome!

Comment: Many thanks for the invitation!  And yes, that's actually one intention of this question... I have one request with your answer: Although a list of equidistributed statistics is also very very nice, I am most interested in *joint* symmetric distributions. (I will clarify this in my question) Could you clarify this in your answer for later use.  (eg. as far as I know, area and bounce are symmetric, but eg. area and dinv are not.) Symmetric distribution implies equidistribution of course...

Comment: Christian, would it be OK for you to split this answer in three? (One for findstat, one for permutations - merged with Patricia's, and one for Dyck paths.)

Comment: Ooops, area and dinv *is* symmetric, bounce and dinv is not, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

For parking functions it is *conjectured* that **dinv** and **area** are symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

### [Eulerian statistics](http://www.findstat.org/Permutations/descents-major#Euler-Mahonian_statistics) on permutations:

A statistic $stat$ is *Eulerian* if it is equidistributed with the number of descents, i.e.,
$$\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}q^{stat(\sigma)} = \sum_{\sigma\in S_n} q^{des(\sigma )}$$
where $S_n$ denotes the group of permutations of $1,\dots ,n$.

The following statistics are Eulerian:

- number of *descents*, this is the number of positions $i$ for which $\sigma_i>\sigma_{i+1}$,
- number of *exceedances*, this is the number of positions $i$ for which $\sigma_i >i$,
- number of *substairs*, as defined in M. Skandera, *An Eurerian partner for inversions*, SLC 46 (2001)
  [I just made up that name, if someone comes up with something better, let me know.]

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of descents and leaves in forests of rooted trees is symmetric. See http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v3i2r8/pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Symmetric statistics on permutations:

- (maj,inv),
- (des,dez),
- (number of crossings, number of nestings)
- (maximal cardinality of a crossing, maximal cardinality of a nesting)

Answer (score 1):

In increasing trees, the depth of the k-th node is equidistributed with the number of edges between two nodes whose labels are consecutive integers <= k, see

[here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/(SICI)1098-2418(199608/09)9:1/2%3C79::AID-RSA5%3E3.0.CO;2-8/abstract)

and

[here](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v17i1r137).

Another, rather curious example: the number of leaves in plane trees, modulo 2, is equidistributed with the internal path length (sum of all distances to the root) modulo 2, see [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669808001649).

Answer (score 0):

### [Mahonian statistics](http://www.findstat.org/Permutations/descents-major#Euler-Mahonian_statistics) on permutations:

A statistic $stat$ is *Mahonian* if it is equidistributed with the major index, i.e.,
$$\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}q^{stat(\sigma)} = \sum_{\sigma\in S_n} q^{maj(\sigma )}$$
where $S_n$ denotes the group of permutations of $1,\dots ,n$.

The following statistics are Mahonian:

- major index, this is the sum of positions $i$ for which $\sigma_i>\sigma_{i+1}$,
- [mazor index](http://www.findstat.org/Permutations/descents-major#A_variation_of_descents_and_major_indices),
- [mafor index](http://www.findstat.org/Permutations/descents-major#A_variation_of_descents_and_major_indices),

Answer (score 0):

### [Euler-Mahonian statistics](http://www.findstat.org/Permutations/descents-major#Euler-Mahonian_statistics) on permutations:

A pair of statistic $stat_1,stat_2$ is *Euler-Mahonian* if it is equidistributed with the bistatistic given by the number of descents and the major index, i.e.,
$$\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}q^{stat_1(\sigma)}t^{stat_2(\sigma)} = \sum_{\sigma\in S_n} q^{des(\sigma)}t^{maj(\sigma)}$$
where $S_n$ denotes the group of permutations of $1,\dots ,n$.

The following statistics are Euler-Mahonian:

- (des,maj),
- (dez,maz), for a definition click [here](http://www.findstat.org/Permutations/descents-major#A_variation_of_descents_and_major_indices)
- (sst,inv), as defined in M. Skandera, An Eurerian partner for inversions, SLC 46 (2001),

Answer (score 0):

### Symmetric statistics on Dyck paths:

The following statistics have a symmetric joint distribution on Dyck paths:

- (area,bounce), see [here](http://www.findstat.org/Dyck%20paths/bounce-dinv)
- (area,dinv), see [here](http://www.findstat.org/Dyck%20paths/bounce-dinv)
- (number of returns, length of last descent)

Answer (score 0):

Symmetric statistics on set partitions:

- (number of crossings, number of nestings)
- (maximal cardinality of a crossing, maximal cardinality of a nesting)

Answer (score 0):

Symmetric statistics on perfect matchings:

- (number of crossings, number of nestings)
- (maximal cardinality of a crossing, maximal cardinality of a nesting)